# Use mod_rewrite to insert string in URL for all files in a directory

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm looking to use mod_rewrite to insert a string before the extension on all files in a specific url. Example:

example.com/products/this-is-a-product.html

add this (-cool):

example.com/products/this-is-a-product-cool.html

to every URL in the /products/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  \.html$ 
RewriteRule ^example.com\/(.+)\.html$   $1-cool.html
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not working. Again, I only want it for all files in the /products/ directory